# The difference between Strong Induction and Proposition 2.2.14 in Terence Tao Analysis I

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction

> Proposition 2.2.14 (Strong principle of induction). Let $m_{0}$ be a
> natural number, and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining to an
> arbitrary natural number m. Suppose that for each $m$ $≥$ $m_{0}$, we
> have the following implication: if $P(m')$ is true for all natural
> numbers $m_{0}$ $≤$ $m′$ $<$ $m$, then $P(m)$ is also true. (In
> particular, this means that P($m_{0}$) is true since in this case, the
> hypothesis is vacuous .) Then we can conclude that $P(m)$ is true for
> all natural numbers $m$ $≥$ $m_{0}$.

Shouldn't it be like this?

> Suppose that for each $m$ $≥$ $m_{0}$, we have the following
> implication: if $P(m')$ is true for all natural numbers $m_{0}$ $≤$
> $m′$ $≤$ $m$, then $P(m+1)$ is also true. (In particular, this means
> that P($m_{0}$) is true since in this case, the hypothesis is vacuous
> .) Then we can conclude that $P(m)$ is true for all natural numbers
> $m$ $≥$ $m_{0}$.

Because that's how strong mathematical induction is used to prove some statement. However, the way Terence Tao states strong mathematical induction is:

> if $P(m')$ is true for all natural numbers $m_{0}$ $≤$
> $m′$ $<$ $m$, then $P(m)$ is also true.

Are these ways of stating using strong mathematical induction equivalent or not? And, how should one use strong mathematical induction the way Terence Tao is using?

Comment: It is: if $P$ holds for every number **less than** $m$, then it holds for $m$. Alternatively: if $P$ holds for every number **less than** $m+1$, then it holds for $m+1$.

Comment: In the second formulation you would need the extra hypothesis that $P(m_0)$ is true as this is not implied by the given condition.